# Replicate subtensors in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor “image_features” having shape `torch.Size([100, 1024, 14, 14])`. I need to replicate each subtensor `(1024, 14, 14)` 10 times, obtaining a tensor having shape `torch.Size([1000, 1024, 14, 14])`.

Basically, the first ten rows of the resulting tensor should correspond to the first row of the original one, the following ten rows of the resulting tensor should correspond to the second row of the original one, and so on. If possible, I don’t want to create a copy (each replicated subtensor can share the memory with the tensor it is replicated from), but it is ok to create a copy if there isn’t any other way.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach that would solve your problem is:

```
orig_shape = (100, 1024, 14, 14)
new_shape = (100, 10, 1024, 14, 14)
input = torch.randn(orig_shape) # [100, 1024, 14, 14]
input = input.unsqueeze(1) # [100, 1, 1024, 14, 14]
input = input.expand(*new_shape) # [100, 10, 1024, 14, 14]
input = input.transpose(0, 1).contiguous() # [10, 100, 1024, 14, 14]
input = input.view(-1, *orig_shape[1:]) # [1000, 1024, 14, 14]
```

We can verify it.

```
orig_shape = (2, 3, 4)
new_shape = (2, 5, 3, 4)
input = torch.randn(orig_shape)
print(input)
input = input.unsqueeze(1)
input = input.expand(*new_shape)
input = input.transpose(0, 1).contiguous()
input = input.view(-1, *orig_shape[1:])
print(input)
```

The code snippet results in:

```
tensor([[[-1.1728,  1.0421, -1.0716,  0.6456],
     [-1.2214,  1.1484, -0.1436,  1.2353],
     [-0.4395, -0.9473, -0.1382, -0.9357]],

    [[-0.4735, -1.4329, -0.0025, -0.6384],
     [ 0.5102,  0.7813,  1.2810, -0.6013],
     [ 0.6152,  1.1734, -0.4591, -1.7447]]])

tensor([[[-1.1728,  1.0421, -1.0716,  0.6456],
     [-1.2214,  1.1484, -0.1436,  1.2353],
     [-0.4395, -0.9473, -0.1382, -0.9357]],

    [[-0.4735, -1.4329, -0.0025, -0.6384],
     [ 0.5102,  0.7813,  1.2810, -0.6013],
     [ 0.6152,  1.1734, -0.4591, -1.7447]],

    [[-1.1728,  1.0421, -1.0716,  0.6456],
     [-1.2214,  1.1484, -0.1436,  1.2353],
     [-0.4395, -0.9473, -0.1382, -0.9357]],

    [[-0.4735, -1.4329, -0.0025, -0.6384],
     [ 0.5102,  0.7813,  1.2810, -0.6013],
     [ 0.6152,  1.1734, -0.4591, -1.7447]]])
```

Comment: I guess that this approach would not copy the subtensor. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using `tensor.repeat()` that involves copying of data:

```
# sample tensor for us to work with
In [89]: shp = (100, 1024, 14, 14)
In [90]: t = torch.randn(shp)

# number of desired repetitions
In [91]: reps = 10

# all the magic happens here
# 10 -> we wish to repeat the entries `reps` times along first dimension
# 1 -> we don't want to repeat along the rest of the dimensions
In [92]: rep_tensor = t.repeat(reps, 1, 1, 1).view(-1, *shp[1:])

In [93]: rep_tensor.shape
Out[93]: torch.Size([1000, 1024, 14, 14])
```

---

Here's a simple example for sanity checking:

```
In [109]: shp = (1, 3, 2)
In [110]: t = torch.randn(shp)

In [111]: t
Out[111]: 
tensor([[[-0.8974,  0.7790],
         [-0.0637, -1.0532],
         [-0.1682, -0.1921]]])

# repeat 3 times along axis 0
In [112]: rep_tensor = t.repeat(3, 1, 1).view(-1, *shp[1:])

In [113]: rep_tensor
Out[113]: 
tensor([[[-0.8974,  0.7790],
         [-0.0637, -1.0532],
         [-0.1682, -0.1921]],

        [[-0.8974,  0.7790],
         [-0.0637, -1.0532],
         [-0.1682, -0.1921]],

        [[-0.8974,  0.7790],
         [-0.0637, -1.0532],
         [-0.1682, -0.1921]]])
```

Comment: since the OP wants to replicate along dim=1 but also wants to, `the first ten rows of the resulting tensor should correspond to the first row of the original one, the following ten rows of the resulting tensor should correspond to the second row of the original one, and so on.`, shouldn't we need a transpose before view?

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch has a single line solution to achieve this:

```
a =  torch.randn(100,1024,14,14) 
b = torch.repeat_interleave(a,10,dim=0)


#a.size() --> torch.Size([100, 1024, 14, 14])
#b.size() --> torch.Size([1000, 1024, 14, 14])
```

The `repeat_interleave()` repeats the values for a given number of times, across a given axis- 10 times in axis 0. It has the below function definition:

`torch.repeat_interleave(input, repeats, dim=None)`